# passing a TStream using Data Snap in Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I am in need of passing a couple things using Data Snap in Delphi XE6  (`TStream` & `TClientdataSet`). Lets start with a `TStream` - maybe what I learn here, I can figure out the `TClientDataSet`.

Here is my attempt, but it throws an error:

> Remote error: Access violaion at address 0040801C in module DSServer.exe

Client demo (DSClient.exe)

```
//RunReportObj is the real object I will be passing to the server method

Procedure TForm8.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RunReportObj: TRunReportObject;
  S: TStream;
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  RunReportObj:= TRunReportObject.Create;
  RunReportObj.ID:= '10101';
  RunReportObj.ReportName:= 'Test';
  RunReportObj.ExportType:= 'PDF';
  S:= TStream.Create;
   try
    S:= ClientModule1.ServerMethods1Client.GetReport(RunReportObj);
    S.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
    FS:= TFileStream.Create(RunReportObj.ReportName + '.' + RunReportObj.ExportType, fmOpenWrite);;
    try
      FS.CopyFrom(S, S.Size);
    finally
      FS.Free;
    end;
   finally
    S.Free;
   end;
end;
```

ClientClassesUnit1.pas

```
function TServerMethods1Client.GetReport(RunReportObj: TRunReportObject): TStream;
begin
  if FGetReportCommand = nil then
  begin
    FGetReportCommand := FDBXConnection.CreateCommand;
    FGetReportCommand.CommandType := TDBXCommandTypes.DSServerMethod;
    FGetReportCommand.Text := 'TServerMethods1.GetReport';
    FGetReportCommand.Prepare;
  end;
  if not Assigned(RunReportObj) then
    FGetReportCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetNull
  else
  begin
    FMarshal := TDBXClientCommand(FGetReportCommand.Parameters[0].ConnectionHandler).GetJSONMarshaler;
    try
      FGetReportCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetJSONValue(FMarshal.Marshal(RunReportObj), True);
      if FInstanceOwner then
        RunReportObj.Free
    finally
      FreeAndNil(FMarshal)
    end
    end;
  FGetReportCommand.ExecuteUpdate;
  Result := FGetReportCommand.Parameters[1].Value.GetStream(FInstanceOwner);
end;
```

Server demo (DSServer.exe)

```
//not really doing anything with the RunReportObj yet,
// just trying to test whether or not I can pass a TStream back first

function TServerMethods1.GetReport(RunReportObj: TRunReportObject): TStream;
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  Writer: TBinaryWriter;
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Writer := TBinaryWriter.Create(result);
    try
      Writer.Write(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('Hello World' + sLineBreak));
    finally
      Writer.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I'm sure I did something foolish :)

Comment: Ask yourself why you assign to S twice in consecutive lines. You've leaked that first stream. Just as well though since you instantiated TStream which is an abstract class. Are you really meant to destroy the second stream.

Comment: The current error is in the final line of TServerMethods1.GetReport. You call free on an uninitialized variable. Did you disable compiler warnings. Why? Or are you not reading them?

Comment: An experienced programmer can see all these basic errors. Some errors are harder though. An inexperienced programmer won't spot them. In all cases debugging will be needed. What you need to do now is learn how to debug. You need to be able to identify the line of code which raises the error. Until you can debug effectively you will struggle.

Comment: I find it very odd that on the client side, `TServerMethods1Client.GetReport()` is assuming ownsership of `RunReportObj` even though `Button1Click()` is the one who created it. If any error happens inside of `GetReport()`, `RunReportObj` will be leaked since no one will free it.  `Button1Click()` should free it when finished using it, and `GetReport()` should not be calling `RunReportObj.Free` at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, good points! Alas, `TServerMethods1Client.GetReport` is  auto-created and any editing will probably be gone next time. Perhaps it would be advisable to create the `TServerMethods1Client` with `InstanceOwner` set to `false`. I  am not sure about other consequences of this, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take care who is responsible for freeing objects sent with DataSnap. `TServerMethods1.GetReport()` should not free the `Result`, as it has to be sent to the client first.  On the other side, the client should not free the `TStream` it gets from `TServerMethods1Client.GetReport()`, as long as `FInstanceOwner` is true (which it is by default).

The first condition is fulfilled more by accident, although as David pointed out, you are freeing the uninitialized local variable Stream.

Without being able to actually test this in the moment, the correct code for the client should look like:

```
Procedure TForm8.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RunReportObj: TRunReportObject;
  S: TStream;
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  RunReportObj:= TRunReportObject.Create;
  RunReportObj.ID:= '10101';
  RunReportObj.ReportName:= 'Test';
  RunReportObj.ExportType:= 'PDF';
  S:= ClientModule1.ServerMethods1Client.GetReport(RunReportObj);
  S.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
  FS:= TFileStream.Create(RunReportObj.ReportName + '.' + RunReportObj.ExportType, fmOpenWrite);;
  try
    FS.CopyFrom(S, S.Size);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And for the server side:

```
function TServerMethods1.GetReport(RunReportObj: TRunReportObject): TStream;
var
  Writer: TBinaryWriter;
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Writer := TBinaryWriter.Create(result);
  try
    Writer.Write(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('Hello World' + sLineBreak));
  finally
    Writer.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: On the server side, `GetReport()` should seek the `Result` stream back to position 0 before returning it to the client, the client should not be responsible for having to seek it. Also, `GetReport()` can be simplified by using `TStreamWriter` instead of `TBinaryWriter`, or using `TStringStream` instead of `TMemoryStream`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your constructive criticisms, notes, and answers. Let me review what you have suggested and what I have and I will respond accordingly.